# Headings when copying data between sheets

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a code that copies data from multiple sheets to master sheet. All the data gets pasted in the 1st row. I was wondering that if there is way where 1st row includes the predefined header and all the data should be pasted into second column underneath the header.

```
    Set CopyRng1 = sh.Range("B3")
        Set CopyRng2 = sh.Range("C3")
        Set CopyRng3 = sh.Range("D3")
        Set CopyRng4 = sh.Range("G3")
        Set CopyRng5 = sh.Range("C5")
        Set CopyRng6 = sh.Range("A8:j25")
        Set CopyRng7 = sh.Range("A28:j45")

        'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
        If Last + CopyRng1.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
            GoTo ExitTheSub
        End If

        'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
        'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A").Resize(CopyRng1.Rows.Count, CopyRng1.Columns.Count).Value = CopyRng1.Value
DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "B").Resize(CopyRng2.Rows.Count, CopyRng2.Columns.Count).Value = CopyRng2.Value
DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "C").Resize(CopyRng3.Rows.Count, CopyRng3.Columns.Count).Value = CopyRng3.Value
DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "D").Resize(CopyRng4.Rows.Count, CopyRng4.Columns.Count).Value = CopyRng4.Value
DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "E").Resize(CopyRng5.Rows.Count, CopyRng5.Columns.Count).Value = CopyRng5.Value
DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "F").Resize(CopyRng6.Rows.Count, CopyRng6.Columns.Count).Value = CopyRng6.Value

Last = LastRow(DestSh)

DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "F").Resize(CopyRng7.Rows.Count, CopyRng7.Columns.Count).Value = CopyRng7.Value
```

Comment: I wonder why do you use `CopyRngN.Columns.Count` for second argument for `Resize` when you paste (as it seems) only one column: A, B, C, D, E, F?

Comment: Becuase copyrng 6 & copyrng7 contains multiple columns

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but then you override previous values - don't you see?

Comment: CopyRng6 contains ("A8:j25") and CopyRng7 contains ("A28:j45"). So when copyrng 6 gets pasted, we reset the lastrow so that copyrng 7 gets pasted underneath the copyrng 6 instead of overwriting it.

Comment: I could be doing wrong as being a novice in VBA, however i got this code to work with the help from the stack community.

Comment: OK. Say, `Last` equals to 1. Then, first row inserts into `A2` cell. When you calculate columns of incoming range, your range will go beyond column `A`. If your `CopyRng1` is, let's say, `A1:J50`, then the pasted data will go from column `A` to column `J`. But on the next line you're inserting into column `B`. Whatever is in CopyRng2, it will override previous values pasted on the previous step.

Comment: For Copyrng 1 to 5 they only contain one cell each. Say Copyrng 1 contains b3, Copy rng 2 contains d5. etc.

Comment: To get back to your question; You can copy the headers from an existing worksheet and paste in the first row of your `DestSh`, another way is to create an array(list) of the headers and write them to the first row.